# How to hgignore all files of a particular extension except in one directory and its subdirectories?

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore

I would like to use the `.hgignore` file of Mercurial to ignore all files with file extension `.tex`, except those `.tex` files in one particular directory and whatever subdirectory of this directory.

I presume `syntax: regexp` will be required for this.
A brief explanation of the particular regular expression used, would also be very welcome, so that we can all learn a bit here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I ignore all directories except one using .hgignore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637496/how-can-i-ignore-all-directories-except-one-using-hgignore)

Comment: @BradRem Not quite, because there is also the file extension issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to exclude the directory named `exclude`. The following regex would then match all files that end in `.tex` unless `exclude/` comes somewhere before that:

```
^(?!.*\bexclude/).*\.tex$
```