# How to define hg ignore exceptions?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore

`gitignore` has the ability to define ignore exception by using optional prefix <kbd>!</kbd>, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203249/2589776), in order not to ignore particular file `foo.dll`:

```
*.dll        # Exclude all dlls
!foo.dll     # Except for foo.dll
```

How can we define such exceptions in `hgignore`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hgignore: help ignoring all files but certain ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512058/hgignore-help-ignoring-all-files-but-certain-ones)

Answer (score 7):

Mercurial only allows exceptions to ignore patterns to be encoded in the same rule that defines the ignore pattern (usually via  `(?!...)`, `(?<!...)` or similar regular expression constructs), even though its matching engine is considerably more powerful (and can in principle match on file size and other things specified in `hg help filesets`).

This has two reasons, composability and performance.

#### Composability

When you have an include/exclude system for patterns, then order matters. Mercurial has various sources for ignore files: The `.hgignore` file in the repository, as well as any `ui.ignore` and `ui.ignore.*` option in a `hgrc` file that Mercurial processes, and every file included by a `include:` directive from the above list. Allowing rules to interact with each other across various ignore files in surprising ways can lead to surprising situations that are difficult to debug. Alternatively, one kind of pattern (inclusion or exclusion) could be prioritized over others, but that poses problems of its own.

#### Performance

Mercurial uses ignore files to prune directory tree walks. If a directory matches an ignore rule, it is skipped in its entirety (such as a build output directory with thousands of temporary files). When you have an ignore pattern that matches a directory, but also an exception that matches a file in the directory, your options are to either not prune the directory walk or to disregard the exception for the directory (Git chooses to do the latter). Not pruning the directory walk is inefficient, disregarding exceptions within the directory severely limits the number of use cases that aren't already handled well by regular expressions.

#### Solution & Workarounds

A major difference between Mercurial and Git is that Mercurial provides the option to use Python's extended regular expressions in addition to glob patterns (Git uses glob patterns only). Regular expressions eliminate the need for exceptions for most (but not all) use cases.

These cases are usually handled adequately via a `re:(?!exception)pattern` line in your `.hgignore` file (and in some cases, other advanced regular expression patterns). Note that the `(?x)` meta pattern, which ignores unescaped whitespace and comments in a regular expression, can be useful to make complex expressions more readable. For example, the following two are equivalent:

```
re:(?x) (^|/) (?!foobar) foo # do not ignore files starting with `foobar`.
re:(^|/)(?!foobar)foo
```

This works reasonably well for ignore files, since file patterns rarely include whitespace or hash symbols. Note also that you can switch to regular expression syntax on a line-by-line basis by prefixing it with `re:` or `regexp:`, even if you normally use `syntax: glob`.

If that is insufficient, is possible to modify the existing behavior via extensions if no other option reasonably applies. You can override `mercurial.dirstate.dirstate.{_ignore,_dirignore}` or you can automatically add `-I/-X` options to the relevant commands based on (say) an `.hginclexcl` file.

Comment: Very thorough, but doesn't clearly answer the question

Comment: This is because the question ("how can we ...") cannot be answered. Git and Mercurial have different mechanisms that cannot fully emulate one another.