# Mercurial. Ignore all except ones, using glob

Tags: mercurial, glob

I want to ignore all except a few folders and files.

I saw examples with regexp. But I don't understand well the regexp and there is  different implementations of the regexp. So, I'm not sure that it will always work correctly.

**Is there a way to invert a glob expressions?**

In node-glob I could write:

`!(pattern|pattern|pattern)` *Matches anything that does not match any of the patterns provided.*

But it doesn't work for Mercurial.

Comment: If you "don't understand well the regexp" - YOU FAIL, because strong understanding of regexo-ing **is a must**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hgignore: help ignoring all files but certain ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512058/hgignore-help-ignoring-all-files-but-certain-ones)

Comment: Put `syntax: regexp` at the top of your `.hgignore`, and you'll be able to use standard, full-powered regular expressions. (Then see the other question for what you could use.)